# ERROR: This branch does not have a default environment issue?

Tags: node.js, git, amazon-web-services, express

I am attempting to launch a NodeJS app on AWS direct link to guide here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_nodejs_express.html

> Screen capture:

[image]

When running the git commit -m "First express app" command I always get this error (everything else works fine up until that point)

> ERROR: This branch does not have a default environment. You must
>   either specify an environment by typing "eb deploy my-env-name" or set
>   a default environment by typing "eb use my-env-name".

If you have overcome a similar experience or can shed light it is more welcome.

Comment: Does executing any of those commands the error message suggests work? If not, what happened when you did?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution

I had the environment in my config but had to call it
inside ***.ebextensions/config.yml*** is the following:

```
branch-defaults:
  default:
    environment: node-express-env
    group_suffix: null
global:
  application_name: my_app_name
  branch: null
  default_ec2_keyname: null
  default_platform: node.js
  default_region: us-east-2
  include_git_submodules: true
  instance_profile: null
  platform_name: null
  platform_version: null
  profile: eb-cli
  repository: null
  sc: git
  workspace_type: Application
```

As such when I modified my command from

> eb deploy

to

> eb deploy node-express-env

it worked.

Answer (score 0):

There is more information on the AWS docs:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli-troubleshooting.html

Solution: Run eb list to see a list of available environments. Then run eb use env-name to use one of the available environments.